# How to call a particular function depending on a particular object's type

Tags: c++, message

```
class Message {};
class BuildSandCastle : public Message {};
class DigHole : public Message {};
```

Given an arbitrary `Message*` object, how can I call a function of the same name `doMessage()` without resorting to switch logic or making a MessageHandler class that has one 'do' function for every message name?

EDIT: for example:

```
class Sandbox
{
public:
  void play(Message* m)
  {
     // call doBuildSandCastle
     // or doDigHole based on m's type
  }
  void doBuildSandCastle();
  void doDigHole();
};
```

Sorry I wasn't clear before.

EDIT:

can someone just delete this train wreck of a question? I really don't want all these highschool lessons in polymorphism.

Comment: Now that your question is clearer... You can either get your message object to call the right function:
`void play(Message* m) { m->play(this); }`

or you could have a map of function pointers in `Sandbox` and execute the appropriate function based on the message name (or typeid), e.g.
`handler_map[m.name()]();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for something like [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184429055)

```
class MessageHandlerBase
{};

template<typename MessageType>
class MessageHandler:
    public virtual MessageHandlerBase
{
    virtual void process(MessageType*)=0;
};

class Message
{
protected:
    template<typename MessageType>
    void dynamicDispatch(MessageHandlerBase* handler,MessageType* self)
    {
        dynamic_cast<MessageHandler<MessageType>&>(*handler).process(self);
    }
};
class Message1:
    public MessageBase
{
    void dispatch(MessageHandlerBase* handler)
    {
        dynamicDispatch(handler,this);
    }
};
```

Except without having to use dynamic_cast, or passing the message itself (a la the code in the original question.)

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: Now that the question has been clarified, here is the new answer:

You can either get your message object to call the right function:

```
void play(Message* m) { m->play(this); }
```

or you could have a map of function pointers in Sandbox and execute the appropriate function based on the message name (or typeid), e.g.

```
handler_map[m.name()]();
```

I would use Boost::function to store function pointers in a map.

---

OLD ANSWER: I think what you need is virtual functions:

```
class Message 
{
  virtual void doMessage { std::cout << "message" << std::endl; }
};
class BuildSandCastle : public Message 
{
  virtual void doMessage { std::cout << "build sand castle" << std::endl; }
};
class BuildSandCastle : public Message 
{
  virtual void doMessage { std::cout << "dig hole" << std::endl; }
};
```

When you call `doMessage` like this:

```
Message* msg = new BuildSandCastle();
msg->doMessage();
```

it will output "build sand castle".

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are just trying to add a polymorphic function to some classes. 
Assuming any parameters and return values are the same on the sub classes, you can add a pure virtual function to the base class.

eg : (note: I didn't compile this, so apologies if there are typos)

```
class Message
{
    public:
    virtual void doMessage() = 0;
};

class BuildSandCaste : public Message
{
    public:
    void doMessage() { /* build a sand castle */ }
};

class DigHole : public Message
{
    public:
    void doMessage() { /* dig hole */ }
};
```

Comment: It's usually a good practice to put `virtual` before every function declaration (not only in the base class), so that somebody who inspects your interface can easily distinguish `virtual` and `non-virtual` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use virtual functions.

```
class Message {
  virtual void doSomething(...) = 0;
};

class ReportMessage : public Message {
  virtual void doSomething(...) {
  // (...) - specific for repors
  }
};

class BankReportMessage : public ReportMessage {
  virtual void doSomething(...) {
  // (...) -||- for banks
  }
};
```

Now, somewhere in your code:

```
Message* my_message = new BankReportMessage(...);
my_message->doSomething(...); // Would call appropriate function
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework, so you should probably look at `virtual` functions ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function)).  Message should probably have pure virtual `doMessage`, which gets overridden in the subclasses.